# C - Choice Not Being Chosen

Tags: c

```
        write(sd, "\nWelcome!\n", 51);
        write(sd, "Please enter one of the following options:\n\n", 45);
        write(sd, "1 - Do this\n", 28);
        write(sd, "2 - Do that\n", 26);
        write(sd, "3 - Do the other\n", 27);
        fflush(stdout);

        recv(sd, &choice, 1, 0);

        switch (choice) {
        case 49:
        fp = popen("/bin/df", "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("Failed to run command\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        while (fgets(path, sizeof(path), fp) != NULL) {
            sgnet_writes(sd, path);

        }
        break;
        default:
        write(sd, "Invalid choice!\n", 17);
        break;
```

So when I type in 49, I get the invalid choice message. Any idea how or at least how to get to the DO SOME STUFF section?

If I type in any number starting with 1, it choose first option, any number starting with 2, the second, any number starting with 3, its the 3rd option. Any number starting with 4 or above, it fails

Thanks

Comment: Positive. If I type in 1, 101, 11111, 1111111111111111111111 then "Do this" happens. If I do any number beginning with 2, then its "Do that"... simialrly for 3

Comment: Cool story. What is `choice`?

Comment: I know, right? The only other reference there is to choice in this file is int choice = 0;

Comment: So `choice` is a variable with type `int`. You could've said that.

Comment: " Any idea how or at least how to get to the DO SOME STUFF section?" - type in a number starting with 1?

Comment: @pee2pee do you check what value is `choice` when you type 49 after the `recv(sd, &choice, 1, 0)` line? because if `sd` is `string` or `char`, then the value copied from `sd` to `choice` could be wrong, since the value for ASCII character "4" is 52

Comment: Thanks @Ian - figured something out that you've helped with!

Answer (score 2):

Always remember to `break` for each `case` of `switch` statement:

```
case 49:
{
    DO SOME STUFF;
}
break;
```

Comment: because you don't have `break`, so it goes straight to `default` which is not what you want.

Comment: I added but nothing changed

Comment: can you put a `printf( "%d\n", choice);` right after your `recv` line, and show the output?

Answer (score 0):

Like artm said, just add a break:

```
    write(sd, "\nWelcome!\n", 51);
    write(sd, "Please enter one of the following options:\n\n", 45);
    write(sd, "1 - Do this\n", 28);
    write(sd, "2 - Do that\n", 26);
    write(sd, "3 - Do the other\n", 27);
    fflush(stdout);

    recv(sd, &choice, 1, 0);

    switch (choice) {
    case 49:
        DO SOME STUFF
        break;
    default:
    write(sd, "Invalid choice!\n", 17);
    break;
```

Comment: Amended original code and I do have this - just didn't want to type what I thought was at the time, sensitive

Comment: the line recv(sd, &choice, 1, 0); might be wrong. You may not be receiving the whole int because your "len" parameter is 1

Comment: So I guess that's why 111111111111 works as does 2222222 and 33333333333. Ok - unfortunately I can't edit this code directly so will need a think

Answer (score 0):

`choice` is a variable of type `int`. An `int` is 4 or 8 bytes on the most common platforms. `read`ing 1 byte into an `int` can yield unpredictable results, so you shouldn't do it.

Additionally, the character '1' is different from the number 1. In fact, the character '1' has a value of 49 (again, on the most common platforms). And `read` reads characters, not numbers - if you type `1`, the first byte it reads will have the value 49.